# signalr - with different clients

Tags: javascript, signalr

I am trying to setup a signalR system.

I have the sample code working, using two browsers and the same hub.   messages are sent and received.

Now, when I created a different page, and try to send messages to the hub, it appears to be kinda working, meaning it doesn't blow up, but nothing gets transmitted to the other clients.

I thought I was accessing the same message hub, from all the clients, but maybe I am missing something.

Is it possible to connect different web sites to the same message hub?

Begin Edit

As requested....  here is the code i am using on my second client...

```
  var connection = $.hubConnection('http://xxxxxxxxx.azurewebsites.net/');
  var contosoChatHubProxy = connection.createHubProxy('MessagePump');
// contosoChatHubProxy.on('Send', function (name, message) {console.log(name + ' ' + message);});


  $.connection.hub.start()
.done(function () {
  console.log('Now connected, connection ID=' + $.connection.hub.id);  // returns an ID
  //      $.connection.hub.send('testing', 'this is a test from the client');
  //      contosoChatHubProxy.send("testing");
  //      contosoChatHubProxy.invoke('testing', 'this is a test for the client 1');
  //      contosoChatHubProxy.invoke('say', 'this is a test for the client 2');
  //      contosoChatHubProxy.invoke('Send', 'This is a test for client 3');
  //      $.connection.hub.send('testing', 'this is a test from the client 4');
  contosoChatHubProxy.invoke('messagePump', 'user', 'this is a test message for 5');
})
.fail(function(){ console.log('Could not Connect!'); });
```

This is what i am seeing in firebug

[image]

From what i can make of the code, the proxy appears to be loading locally, and not even seeing the remote system hub...

My console application(s) that only connect to the remote system hub are able to send and receive messages.

btw - i have tried upper can lower case (MessagePump, messagePump)
but it has not changed the result.

Comment: You should add your relevant code in order to get assistance

Comment: Yep, you need to show your working otherwise it's difficult to say what the issue is :-) My guess would be you that need to look overriding the OnConnected method of the Hub instance in order to put your connected clients into appropriate groups, and then make sure you send messages to the right group. Your use case is pretty normal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 var connection = $.hubConnection('http://xxxxxxxxx.azurewebsites.net/');
```

You are trying to connect a different website. This `http://xxxxxxxxx.azurewebsites.net/` should let cross domain requests.Otherwise you can't connect. If you can manage `http://xxxxxxxxx.azurewebsites.net/`, you should configure signalr like:

> ```
>    public class Startup
>      {
>         public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
>         {
>             // Branch the pipeline here for requests that start with "/signalr"
>             app.Map("/signalr", map =>
>             {
>                 // Setup the CORS middleware to run before SignalR.
>                 // By default this will allow all origins. You can 
>                 // configure the set of origins and/or http verbs by
>                 // providing a cors options with a different policy.
>                 map.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
>                 var hubConfiguration = new HubConfiguration 
>                 {
>                     // You can enable JSONP by uncommenting line below.
>                     // JSONP requests are insecure but some older browsers (and some
>                     // versions of IE) require JSONP to work cross domain
>                     // EnableJSONP = true
>                 };
>                 // Run the SignalR pipeline. We're not using MapSignalR
>                 // since this branch already runs under the "/signalr"
>                 // path.
>                 map.RunSignalR(hubConfiguration);
>             });
>         }
>     }
> ```